# Best SEO plugin for Craft CMS - SEOmatic vs SEO plugin

Tags: seo

SEOmatic vs SEO plugin (https://github.com/ethercreative/seo) - which one is better? Ignoring the fact that one is paid and one is free.

I'm creating a blog site and I need to also implement SEO related functionalities.

Answer (score 4):

I have used SEOmatic for years on Craft 2, but since it became a paid plugin on Craft 3 I trialled other SEO plugins.

I realised the extra work needed to make other plugins have a result like SEOmatic's wasn't worth the time over the extra cost to install SEOmatic and be on my way.

I'd recommend SEOmatic, but if you have the time to make a free SEO plugin do what you need it to do, then go for it.

Answer (score 3):

**Bias warning:** I am the author of [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic) for Craft CMS 3, so I'm obviously not impartial here. However, what I'd suggest you do is install the both, and try them out. You can do that pretty easily with the Craft Plugin Store.

I think you will find that [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic) has many features that aren't available elsewhere, but depending on your needs, that may not matter to you.